# Lack of data replication in data list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i want to show countdown time for product but  The countdown timer is not displayed in all rows.Only the first line is shown.

i want show count time for all records in data list , what should i do?

```
            <div id="timelabel"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            var leave = <%=seconds%> ;


            CounterTimer();
            var interv=setInterval(CounterTimer,1000);


            function CounterTimer()
            {
                var day = Math.floor(leave / ( 60 * 60 * 24))
                var hour = Math.floor(leave / 3600) - (day * 24)
                var minute = Math.floor(leave / 60) - (day * 24 *60) - (hour * 60)
                var second = Math.floor(leave) - (day * 24 *60*60) - (hour * 60 * 60) - (minute*60)


                hour=hour<10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
                minute=minute<10 ? "0" + minute : minute;
                second=second<10 ? "0" + second : second;


                var remain=day + " days   "+hour + ":"+minute+":"+second;
                leave=leave-1;


                document.getElementById("timelabel").innerHTML=remain;


            }

            </script>   
            <br /><br />
            product_Id:
            <asp:Label ID="product_IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("product_Id") %>' />
            <br />
            product_name:
            <asp:Label ID="product_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("product_name") %>' />     

          </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're mixing server side code and client side code, you didn't consider that on the client side the ID of an element should be unique. The getElementById therefore only returns the first element it finds (note it isn't called getElement**s**ById).

For easier javascript, you should include / use jQuery, so add a reference to it in your page.

Change your html for the timelabel to:

```
<div class="timelabel" data-leave="<%=seconds%>"></div>
```

I suspect you run the code inside a repeater. Your function is defined again for each item in the repeater, so move the script outside the repeater:

```
function CounterTimer(labelElement)
{
  var leave = parseInt(labelElement.data("leave"));
  var day = Math.floor(leave / ( 60 * 60 * 24))
  var hour = Math.floor(leave / 3600) - (day * 24)
  var minute = Math.floor(leave / 60) - (day * 24 *60) - (hour * 60)
  var second = Math.floor(leave) - (day * 24 *60*60) - (hour * 60 * 60) - (minute*60)

  hour=hour<10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
  minute=minute<10 ? "0" + minute : minute;
  second=second<10 ? "0" + second : second;

  var remain=day + " days   "+hour + ":"+minute+":"+second;
  leave=leave-1;
  labelElement.data("leave",leave);
  labelElement.text(remain);
}
function UpdateCounters() {
  $( ".timelabel" ).each(function() {
    CounterTimer($( this ));
  });
}

$(function() {
  UpdateCounters();
  setInterval(UpdateCounters,1000)
});
```

See a working implementation of this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mor46k5q/

What it does is instead of IDs to identify multiple elements, it uses the class of the element identifying elements. Secondly instead of writing a global variable which cannot be reused by multiple rows, the data is stored in the DOM object of the label. At last a code is modified such that it runs on all timelabel elements found in the document.

A few observations though: as you're using the seconds left, you don't have an exact timing (how long did it take between you determined the seconds left on the server and the start of the javascript execution on the client). Secondly, the decrement of leave with one assumes the function is called every second. This needs to be in sync with the setInterval timings.

Comment: My main problem is that when the Timer or any other timer in the data list  set The timer is displayed in the first row. Do not show in the next row

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var leave =60;

        function CounterTimer()
        {
            var day = Math.floor(leave / ( 60 * 60 * 24))
            var hour = Math.floor(leave / 3600) - (day * 24)
            var minute = Math.floor(leave / 60) - (day * 24 *60) - (hour * 60)
            var second = Math.floor(leave) - (day * 24 *60*60) - (hour * 60 * 60) - (minute*60)

            hour=hour<10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
            minute=minute<10 ? "0" + minute : minute;
            second=second<10 ? "0" + second : second;

            var remain=day + " days   "+hour + ":"+minute+":"+second;
            leave=leave-1;


            document.getElementById("timelabel").innerHTML=remain;


        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It would be better if you'd explain your code and why it helps.

Comment: My main problem is that when the Timer or any other timer in the data set

The timer is displayed in the first row.
Do not show in the next row.

Comment: My main problem is that when the Timer or any other timer in the data list  set

The timer is displayed in the first row.
Do not show in the next row.